# Copy text from div to textarea and make it work without integration in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to copy value from `div` to `textarea` and it works. But I want to use content of `textarea` in my `javascript` and if I don't click in text area and use for example "space bar" it doesn't work :/ I need to click here and write anything to make it work. But I want to make it work without editing anything manually. I want to have in textarea only copy of `div`. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Editor</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
#editor { 
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="src-min/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div id="editor"></div>
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" id="output">
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button> 
<script>

function myFunction() {
var code = editor.getSession().getValue();
    console.log(code);
    console.log(document.getElementById('output').innerHTML);
    var test = document.getElementById('input');
    console.log(test.value);
}
       var textarea = $('#input');

   var editor = ace.edit("editor");
   editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
   editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/sh");

   editor.getSession().on('change', function () {
       textarea.val(editor.getSession().getValue());
   });

   textarea.val(editor.getSession().getValue());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And "budle.js" file:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var error = document.getElementById('error');

input.addEventListener('change', update);
input.addEventListener('input', update); 

function update() {
  try {
    var value = parse(input.value);
    output.textContent = JSON.stringify(value, null, 2);
    error.textContent = '';
  } catch (e) {
    error.textContent = String(e);
  }
}
```

@edit

So I want to send content of `textarea` without any integration, but like now I need to click for example spacebar in it to make it work :/

Comment: So at what point in the users interaction do you want editor.getSession().getValue()? It seems that you have all the code you need, but the code actually evaluate your current code.

Comment: I want it for example in "bundle.js" or I want to make my second code, where I'm copying div into textarea, to work without any changes (like making spacebar) in textarea.

Comment: Try to trigger change event for textarea in jquery before input.addEventListener('change',update);